# how to split one column into multiple variable columns in parse.com

Tags: ios, mysql, database, swift, parse-platform

I have the following records in my data base

```
fields:   brand |model |attributes
          ----------------------------
record 1) apple |iPhone|6s space grey sprint
record 2) audi  | a6   |quattro coupe
```

How can I store the attributes into different column names, with  version/color/carrier columns for the first record and engine/type as the different columns for second record. The table should have 5 total columns for 1st record and 4 columns for the second record.

How do I achieve this? Should I split the table? If there are million products and each have varied length attributes then the number of columns in the table will be long. Whats the efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the related attributes in a second table.

```
record|attribute|value
------+---------+-----
1     |version  |6s       
1     |color    |space grey
1     |carrier  |sprint
2     |engine   |quattro
2     |type     |coupe
```

This would allow for an item to have any number of (optional) attributes.